# How to ignore space between minutes and meridian in date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-fns

It's here a way to tell `date-fns` to ignore white space in the `parse` method? I'm migrating from `momentjs` to `date-fns` and I noticed that `date-fns` does a strict parse, which is not the case with `momentjs`

```js
// moment.js

moment('09:30PM', 'hh:mm A').toDate(); // -> with whitespace
//Fri Sep 18 2020 21:30:00

moment('09:30 PM', 'hh:mm A').toDate(); // -> without whitespace
//Fri Sep 18 2020 21:30:00


// date-fns
parse('09:30 PM', 'hh:mm aa', new Date()); // -> with whitespace
//Fri Sep 18 2020 21:30:00

parse('09:30PM', 'hh:mm aa', new Date()); // -> without whitespace
// Invalid date
```

It's there a way to ignore those white spaces in `date-fns`?

Comment: Remove the space if there is one before parsing: `parse('09:30 PM'.replace(/\s*(\w\w)$/,'$1'), 'hh:mmaa', new Date())`.

Comment: yeah, my question was more, if there is a way for the library to do it. but thanks.